# How to get notified when a PHP/SQL query is notworking or invalid?

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem. So I thought I should post my question here. I want to know that if my query is invalid how can I code the query so that the PHP controller notify me about the query error. Here is my PHP query code.

```
 //assuming that the link $link to sql db has been already made
$Result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM books-table');
```

Is it possible to get notified whenever the query is wrong? please help

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'wrong'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it. You can add an `if condition` to your code and use `mysqli_error` function to notify you about the invalid queries. Also you should save the query in a variable if you want to echo it easily so that you can also see the query. Here is your code with changes:

```
$yourquery = 'SELECT * FROM books-table';
$Result = mysqli_query($link, $yourquery);  
if(!$Result)
{
    echo 'There is an error in your query. Error='. mysqli_error($link);//to display error
    echo '</br> the query is: '. $yourquery; //to display the query
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

To capture if the query generates an error, you can code it like this:

```
/* OO-style */
if (!$link->query('SELECT * FROM books-table')) {
    echo "Error: ".$link->error;
}

/* procedural style */
if (!mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM books-table')) {
    echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($link);
}
```

(see the [description of mysqli-query here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) in the php manual)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something as simple as:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT XXname FROM customer_table ";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);

if (!$mysqli->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

?>
```

Courtesy - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_query("SOME_QUERY"))
{
//working do some action
}
else
{
//not working do some action
}
```